# High Contrast Theme Disable Cursor/Text Dotted Border

Tags: visual-studio-code, high-contrast

I have been using vscodes default high contrast theme for years; somewhere in the past few releases a dotted box has been introduced, but I can't find anything in the release notes about it and inspecting tokens doesn't help. Can't narrow it down with developer window either.

Is there a way to disable / alter the white dotted border:

[image]

It appears to be reproducible in these scenarios:

- Place cursor anywhere in the word boundary and navigate to any other panel/ui element that's not the editor (using shortcuts or mouse doesn't matter)
- Pressing Ctrl+F anywhere on the word

I am currently using vscode 1.75

Comment: @user on the word / for the word is semantically the same in this context imo; for brevity - just means initiating a find and replace

Comment: well if you're stuck on the semantics of pressing Ctrl F anywhere on a word boundary and pressing Ctrl F with a selection of the word/partial word then there's nothing I can do here. Thanks for checking in though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue: [find match highlight border color](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173262) - seems to be a **reversion** see

[Borders styles for selection and word highlight](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45479):

> We can do solid border styles for anything except high contrast. In
> the high contrast theme, the same color is used for all of these
> decorations and the only distinguishable trait is the border style.

But a PR was submitted and merged (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/46956) to change the dotted high contrast theme `find...` border colors to solid.  So you should upvote the first issue mentioned above.

---

A workaround has been provided until a css rule has been corrected, see

> This can be turned off via `"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false`. The
> root cause is an incorrect CSS rule.

from [find match highlight border color](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173262#issuecomment-1437515499).

Comment: Ah. Good catch Mark. Thanks. I always forget to check github. It sucks because it isn't just a find and replace occurrence; I thought it was accessibility related because high contrast for one, and also it happens anytime I switch from 1 editor to another or from the editor to any other panel (without selection or anything, just as long as the cursor is on the word). It seems like their solution is to just make it solid. It would be cool if it was just on find and replace I'll post my feedback on the issue you linked. Thanks so much

Comment: A solution was provided in the first github link you provided Mark; care to update your answer? Or care if I do it?